# Problems with Panel in Xubuntu 22.04

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, xfce-panel

I am really struggling with the Panel in Xubuntu 22.04
sometimes it just disappears, sometimes elements are missing,sometimes removing an element causes the panel to crash/disappear, I seem to have intermittent difficulty saving the panel setup etc. (if I try to save it nothing happens).
So, I reinstalled the panel, and - as far as I understand it - removing the configuration :
[see https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=344023]

```
xfce4-panel --quit   
pkill xfconfd    
rm -rf ~/.config/xfce4/panel      
rm -rf ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-panel.xml    
xfce4-panel
```

after this the panel looked "new" , but am  still getting a long error message, for example - after the panel disappeared again - running the command
`xfce4-panel`
leads to this output:

```
(wrapper-2.0:6872): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 12:45:23.161: g_file_new_for_path: assertion 'path != NULL' failed
(wrapper-2.0:6872): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 12:45:23.161: g_file_monitor_file: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
(wrapper-2.0:6872): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 12:45:23.161: invalid (NULL) pointer instance
(wrapper-2.0:6872): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 12:45:23.161: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
(wrapper-2.0:6872): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:45:23.161: Attempting to add a widget with type GtkToggleButton to a container of type XfcePanelPlugin, but the widget is already inside a container of type XfcePanelPlugin, please remove the widget from its existing container first.
** (wrapper-2.0:6873): WARNING **: 12:45:23.170: No outputs have backlight property
(wrapper-2.0:6868): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:45:23.201: Negative content width -3 (allocation 1, extents 2x2) while allocating gadget (node button, owner GtkToggleButton)
(wrapper-2.0:6872): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:45:23.217: Negative content width -3 (allocation 1, extents 2x2) while allocating gadget (node button, owner GtkToggleButton)
(wrapper-2.0:6874): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:45:23.258: Negative content width -3 (allocation 1, extents 2x2) while allocating gadget (node button, owner PulseaudioButton)
(wrapper-2.0:6871): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:45:23.271: Negative content width -3 (allocation 1, extents 2x2) while allocating gadget (node button, owner GtkToggleButton)
(wrapper-2.0:6873): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 12:45:23.281: gtk_icon_theme_has_icon: assertion 'icon_name != NULL' failed
(wrapper-2.0:6873): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 12:45:23.281: gtk_icon_theme_has_icon: assertion 'icon_name != NULL' failed
(wrapper-2.0:6873): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 12:45:23.285: gtk_icon_theme_has_icon: assertion 'icon_name != NULL' failed
(wrapper-2.0:6873): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 12:45:23.287: gtk_icon_theme_has_icon: assertion 'icon_name != NULL' failed
(wrapper-2.0:6873): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:45:23.311: Negative content width -3 (allocation 1, extents 2x2) while allocating gadget (node button, owner PowerManagerButton)
2022-07-08T10:50:01.612846Z  INFO authenticator::application: Authenticator (com.belmoussaoui.Authenticator)
2022-07-08T10:50:01.614121Z  INFO authenticator::application: Version: 4.1.6 ()
2022-07-08T10:50:01.614126Z  INFO authenticator::application: Datadir: /app/share/authenticator
2022-07-08T10:50:05.175240Z  INFO authenticator::models::database: Running DB Migrations...
2022-07-08T10:50:05.175522Z  INFO authenticator::models::database: Database pool initialized.*
```

just to clarify, the panel is back after running **xfce4-panel** and it seems functional, occasionally some elements are missing (like weather plugin or Network applet), then running **xfce4-panel -r** *sometimes* solves the problem. Or I need to reinstall the Weather applet or Network applet.

**Sorry forgot to mention initially** - I may not have a "completely clean" installation of Xubuntu 22.04. I initially had a clean install, but then it kept crashing (which included some of the panel issues mentioned above already happening *before* installing Budgie), so I removed Xubuntu and installed as a "trial" Ubuntu Budgie, but then reverted back to Xubuntu via Timeshift when Budgie also "misbehaved".

However I think that panel preferences are in /home folder, which is not being backed up via Timeshift. so perhaps there is (still) conflict with "Budgie Settings" and XFCE/Xubuntu settings??

actually, under .config there were still 5 Folders like
*budgie-app-launcher budgie-control-center budgie-desktop budgie-extras and budgie-welcome*. I deleted all of them. lets see what happens...

how do I solve this issue?
thanks so much!

**update 10 July.** seems that removing the remaining budgie folders under .config made all the difference. so far so good...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete all the remaining budgie folders under .config that were left over from the "trial" Ubuntu Budgie installation.

budgie-app-launcher
  budgie-control-center
  budgie-desktop
  budgie-extras
  budgie-welcome

Comment: yes, that was what I did and the problems with the Panel seemed to have disappeared 95%. thanks!